# TSQL not using indexes

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

This is a test senario, made with temporary tables to illustrate the problem.
Pretend table @userdata has index on userid
and table @users has index on id

Why is the first select unable to use index, I assumed it would perform better in 1 subselect than in 2 subselects?

Version - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM)
Compatibility level - SQL Server 2000.

```
-- test tables
DECLARE @userdata TABLE(info VARCHAR(50), userid INT)
DECLARE @users    TABLE(id INT, username VARCHAR(20), superuser BIT)

-- test data
INSERT @users    VALUES(1, 'superuser', 1)
INSERT @users    VALUES(2, 'testuser1', 0)
INSERT @users    VALUES(3, 'testuser2', 0)
INSERT @userdata VALUES('secret information', 1)
INSERT @userdata VALUES('testuser1''s data', 2)
INSERT @userdata VALUES('testuser2''s data', 3)
INSERT @userdata VALUES('testuser2''s data',3)

DECLARE @username VARCHAR(50)
SET @username = 'superuser'
--SET @username = 'testuser1'


--The superuser can read all data
--The testusers can only read own data

-- This sql can't use indexes and is very slow
SELECT *
FROM @userdata d
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM @users u
WHERE u.username = @username AND u.superuser = 1 OR 
u.id = d.userid AND u.username = @username)

-- This sql uses indexes and performs well
SELECT *
FROM @userdata d
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM @users u
WHERE u.username = @username AND u.superuser = 1)
OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @users u
WHERE u.ID = d.userid 
AND u.username = @username)
```

Comment: What version of sql server are you using?

Comment: I included the version in my question

Comment: How many rows are in the tables (and rows per user), and how does `SELECT * FROM @userdata d WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @users u WHERE u.username = @username AND (u.superuser = 1 OR u.id = d.userid))` perform relative to the other two queries?

Comment: The select in your first WHERE EXISTS looks off. Shouldn't there be some extra parens in there, maybe: WHERE (u.username = @username AND u.superuser = 1) OR 
(u.id = d.userid AND u.username = @username)?

Comment: @rsbarro - `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` - the parenthetical you've shown is how the server interprets it anyway.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OK, my mistake. Thanks. Still think those parens make it easier to see what's going on though... =]

Comment: I have around 40 k users and around 1 million userdata. Putting in more parenteses makes no difference (I tried). As Damien mentioned AND takes percendence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `or` can cause some trouble for the query analyzer to come up with a good query plan.
This is not really an answer to your question but an alternative way of doing this query. Apart from the index you already have I would suggest an index on @users.username.

```
if exists(select * from @users where username = @username and superuser = 1)
begin
  select *
  from @userdata
end
else
begin
  select d.*
  from @userdata as d
    inner join @users as u
      on d.userid = u.id
  where u.username = @username
end
```

Comment: the last sql takes less than 1 second, first sql takes around 5 seconds. So adding index to username isnt nessasary, at least not yet. The company that sold us the program/database will revoke all support if I make the slightest change.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server won't always produce the optimal plan when you use local variables (@username in your case).

See the following link for an example where SQL Server do not use an index because a local variable is used: http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/using-local-variables-in-t-sql-queries/ .

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the problem is SQL **wont** use the indexes, not that it can't. Their are a variety of reasons for this.

You can try to [force it to use an index](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/07/sql-server-introduction-to-force-index-query-hints-index-hint/). You might find the query is slower that way.

You can try [`ALTER INDEX ixFoo REBUILD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) to rebuild the index. The index might not be used since it is excessively fragmented.

You can also try [`UPDATE STATISTICS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx).

Comment: I don't think the index is the issue. As i mentioned, when i split up the "exists" the sql uses the indexes just fine.